# Using overloaded functions with classes, can't figure out where the garbage is coming from

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I'm working on this program in which a user can enter a day number or a month and day to get the other.

Problem I'm having is when make an instance of the class and pass it to the constructor, it displays the day # correctly, but when it calls print I get garbage. If I initialize day to 0 it will say day is 182, but then when print is called it prints 0.

It works perfect on DayOfYear(), but not DayOfYear(int day).

I'm stumped.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;





//class declaration
class DayOfYear
{
private:

    static const int MonthDays[];
    static const string MonthName[];
public:
    //static const int MonthDays[];
    //static const string MonthName[];
    int day;

    DayOfYear();
    DayOfYear(int day);
    DayOfYear(string month_, int day_);
    void print();   
};

DayOfYear::DayOfYear()
{
    cout << "\nEnter a number you would like to convert into a month and day: ";
    cin >> day;

    //Error check for negative numbers and numbers higher than one year
    while(day <= 0 || day > 365)
    {
        cout << "You must enter a valid number (1 thru 365)" << endl;
        cin>>day;
    }

    //call print() function
    print();
}





DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int day)
{
    cout<<"\nDay of the year"<<day<<"is";
    print();

}    

DayOfYear::DayOfYear(string month_,int day_)
{
    int count=0;

    while (month_ != DayOfYear::MonthName[count])
    {count++;}

    int result = DayOfYear::MonthDays[count] + day_;

    cout<<"Day number= "<<result<<endl;
}


//days of each month into an array
const int DayOfYear::MonthDays[] = {31, 28, 31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
//name of each month into an array
const string DayOfYear::MonthName[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};






void DayOfYear::print()
{
    int month = 0;
    //int day_=0;
    //day_=day;
    cout<<"\nprint start day: "<<day<<endl;
    while ((DayOfYear::MonthDays[month] < day)&& (month<11)){
        day=day-DayOfYear::MonthDays[month];
        month++;
    cout<<"/nprint month: "<<month<<" day: "<<day<<endl;
    }
    cout << DayOfYear::MonthName[month] << " " << day;
};


int main()
{   
    int day=0;

    DayOfYear();
    DayOfYear halfway(365/2);
    //halfway.print();


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: DayOfWeek?  All I see is DayOfYear in code...make sure you post the correct code, and exactly what your inputs and outputs are

Comment: It's impossible that it "works perfect on DayOfWeek(), but not DayOfWeek(int day).", because your code contains nether of those functions.

Comment: Constructors really shouldn't do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the `day` member in your `DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int)` constructor. Change this line:

```
DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int day)
```

to this:

```
DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int day_) : day(day_)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `DayOfYear(int day)` constructor you are never assigning your private variable, I would do something like this

```
DayOfYear::DayOfYear(int inDay)
{
    day = inDay;
    cout<<"\nDay of the year"<<day<<"is";
    print();

}
```

Comment: Someone mentioned another way up above.  This is what that does. I should've known this. THanks!